# CiviCRM Upgrade Fails Between 5.65.2 and 5.67.3

Tags: upgrade, database

I am trying to upgrade between CiviCRM 5.65.2 and 5.67.3. My CMS is Drupal 9.5.

During the upgrade I get the following error.

Upgrade DB to 5.65.alpha1: SQL (CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FiveSixtyFive::runSql(5.65.alpha1))

Cannot execute CREATE TABLE `snap_civicrm_v5_65_group` ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED AS   SELECT id, name, title, frontend_title, description, frontend_description
FROM civicrm_group
WHERE name IS NULL OR frontend_title IS NULL OR frontend_title = "" OR frontend_description IS NULL OR frontend_description = "": DB Error: no such field

I have checked and my DB User has "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES"

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `civicrm_prod`.* TO 'civi_user'@'%'
```

I am not sure how to get more information about this error to resolve this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is actually with the Snapshot system as part of the upgrade.  I changed

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this further, it appears the issue is that my civicrm_group table does not have a title or a frontend_title.  I have title_ each of my languages and the same for frontend_title.  For example: frontend_titlle_en_US and frontend_title_es_ES

Tracing it a bit past that I found that the issue did not appear to be related to the upgrade script.

I did not know much about the database snapshots taken but I had a hunch it came from there.

I change the "CIVICRM_UPGRADE_SNAPSHOT" variable to FALSE. I was able to continue the upgrade with the cv command past where it was failing before.

I am going to look at this bit further and try and put in a ticket on CiviCRM GitLab.  I am guessing the issue is with Snapshots and multi-lingual tables.

Comment: That's strange because there is code that is supposed to skip snapshots if multilingual. What do you have in the civicrm_domain table for locales? See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/b3977df112c547f4b2e446ad2db76d70171ecd75/CRM/Upgrade/Snapshot.php#L89

Comment: @Demerit, sorry I did not get back to you sooner.  I have "en_USes_ESpt_PTfr_FR" in my locales field. I found this using "select locales from civicrm_domain;"

Comment: Ok then it seems like it should have skipped the snapshots, because that's what it checks to see if it's multilingual. So I'm not sure why it didn't.